# Issue with optimizing in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, query-optimization

I have asp.net mvc 4 project. And I want to optimize it by deleting all links to jquery from view and move it to bundle in the bottom of the page in my layout page. But I saw that in my View page stop to working some of my jquery functions. And dont know why, may anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's any inline Javascript using jQuery (which there shouldn't be as it's not best practice), then jQuery needs to be referenced before those calls.

Similarly, if you have external JS files which use jQuery, they must be referenced after the jQuery reference.

Comment: I have a bootstrap.js file which isn't corresponding on actions when i move reference to jqury library from view to layout

Comment: There's no dependency between bootstrap and jQuery but they can work side by side. Are there any error messages in the browser console? Try moving jQuery to the top of the JS references at the bottom of the page. I.E - the first reference

Comment: No we have a dependency between bootstrap and jquery. No errors in console. JQuery is the first executable bundle.

Comment: I meant that Bootstrap doesn't need jQuery to work, so the bootstrap functionality should work. Have you checked the page source to ensure that the bundle is correctly rendering the jQuery file? It fails silently if there's a problem. Other than that, you're going to need to share some code to allow anyone identify the problem

Comment: But in bootstrap documentation write that it depends from jquery and when I install it from nuget it was check jquery dependency.

Comment: You're actually correct. jQuery needs to be referenced before the Bootstrap file as demonstrated here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/